# Eclipse failed to start with exit code 160 when enable debug mode

Tags: eclipse, debug-mode, rational-rsa

I am trying to enable debugging mode in Rational Software Architect 9.6 (eclipse based) on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. I followed the instructions in this link for [Setting up the pluglet debugging support](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS5JSH_9.5.0/com.ibm.xtools.pluglets.ui.doc/topics/t_setupdebug.html).

I created a new eclipse_debug.ini as follows:

```
-vm
jdk/jre/bin/javaw
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-install
/opt/IBM/SDP_96
--launcher.GTK_version
--launcher.appendVmargs
2
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Xcompressedrefs
-Xj9
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,onthrow=com.ibm.xtools.pluglets.ui.internal.debug.PlugletDebugException,address=8000
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

Then I try to lunch it using the following command:

```
/opt/IBM/SDP_96$ /opt/IBM/SDP_96/eclipse -product com.ibm.rational.rsa4ws.product.v96.ide --launcher.ini ./eclipse_debug.ini
```

However it failed to start with the following error message:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=160
/opt/IBM/SDP_96//jdk/jre/bin/javaw
-Xquickstart
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Xcompressedrefs
-Xj9
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,onthrow=com.ibm.xtools.pluglets.ui.internal.debug.PlugletDebugException,address=8000
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-jar /opt/IBM/SDP_96//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /opt/IBM/SDP_96/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /opt/IBM/SDP_96//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444/eclipse_1617.so
-startup /opt/IBM/SDP_96//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 1ea20025
-install /opt/IBM/SDP_96 2
-product com.ibm.rational.rsa4ws.product.v96.ide
-vm /opt/IBM/SDP_96//jdk/jre/bin/javaw
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Xcompressedrefs
-Xj9
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,onthrow=com.ibm.xtools.pluglets.ui.internal.debug.PlugletDebugException,address=8000
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
-jar /opt/IBM/SDP_96//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
```

and it dump error starts with the following in the command screen

```
21:29:11.842 ERROR: [OptionParser.cpp:180] Specify launch=<command line> when using onthrow or onuncaught option
21:29:11.842 ERROR: [OptionParser.cpp:180] Specify launch=<command line> when using onthrow or onuncaught option
21:29:11.842  INFO: [Agent.cpp:345] JDWP error: Bad agent options: transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,onthrow=com.ibm.xtools.pluglets.ui.internal.debug.PlugletDebugException,address=8000
21:29:11.842  INFO: [Agent.cpp:345] JDWP error: Bad agent options: transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,onthrow=com.ibm.xtools.pluglets.ui.internal.debug.PlugletDebugException,address=8000
JVMJ9TI064E Agent initialization function Agent_OnLoad failed for library jdwp, return code -1
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000004 Signal_Number=0000000b Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000080
```

So what is the problem for what I am doing? I am following instructions and I am not clear what is the problem. I validated the ini file and it is not including any hidden characters.

I appreciate your help

Comment: "Specify launch=<command line> when using onthrow or onuncaught option" is mentioned in the error output, and I do not see it listed among your argument value.

Comment: it is listed in the line: 
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,onthrow=com.ibm.xtools.pluglets.ui.internal.debug.PlugletDebugException,address=8000

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the following and it works .. at least eclipse started in the debug mode and I was able to lunch the pluglet debugger.

I removed the `onthrow` part from the above `-Xrunjdwp` option so the eclipse_debug.ini is now looks like the following:

```
-vm
jdk/jre/bin/javaw
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-install
/opt/IBM/SDP_96
--launcher.GTK_version
--launcher.appendVmargs
2
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms512m
-Xmx1536m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:name=IBMSDP_%u
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-Xcompressedrefs
#Added by A.Ibrahim
-Xj9
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000
-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true
```

And this option is now is :

**`-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`**

And it works OK.